# Most efficient way to pass arguments (including std::function) to constructor in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

The multithreaded program is similar to the following:

```cpp
struct Timer {
   Timer (boost::asio::io_service& ios) : timer_{ios} {}
   boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

struct TimerContext {
   void                *ctxt_{nullptr};
   void                *cookie_{nullptr};
   TimerEventCallback   teCallback_{nullptr};
};

class A {
   std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)>    callback_;
   int                                                  id_;
   std::string                                          name_;
   boost::asio::io_service                              ios_;
   std::thread                                          thread_;
};
```

A's constructor:

```cpp
A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb, int id, std::string name) :
   callback_{cb},
   id_{id},
   name_{name}
{
   thread_ = std::thread{[this] () {
         // some code
      }
   };
}
```

The callback function definition (free function as of now, written by me):

```cpp
void
customCallback (Timer *timer, const TimerContext& ctxt) {
   log << __func__ << "timer id: " << (void *)timer;

   auto ret = ctxt.teCallback_(timer, ctxt.cookie_);

   log << __func__ << ret;
}
```

In main(),

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   int id = getId(i);
   std::string name = getName(i);

   A *a = new A{customCallback, id, name};

   vectorA.push_back(a);

}
```

I can think of two approaches:

1. Pass constructor arguments by value and then `std::move` them in the constructor initializer list.

```cpp
A *a = new A{customCallback, id, name};

A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb, int id, std::string name) :
   callback_{std::move(cb)},
   id_{std::move(id)},
   name_{std::move(name)}
```

2. Pass constructor arguments by `const` reference and then and allow the copy to occur in the constructor initializer list.

```cpp
A *a = new A{customCallback, id, name};

A::A (const std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> &cb, const int &id, const std::string &name) :
   callback_{cb},
   id_{id},
   name_{name}
```

Which one would be more efficient in terms of **copy and performance**?
If there is a better approach (till and including `c++14`), please suggest.

Comment: If you really care, implement it both ways and measure. I would expect no measurable difference. `std::function` wrapping a plain function pointer would likely use a small object optimization to avoid heap allocation, so both copy and move involve just copying a small handful of bytes. In any case, even if there were heap allocation, it would be absolutely dwarfed by networking overheads (I assume you deal with networking since you use `boost::asio``)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, "so both copy and move involve just copying a small handful of bytes."
 sizeof cb/callback_ in above example is 24.

Comment: So, I expect copying 24 bytes would be too fast to measure. It is highly unlikely to be a bottleneck, or a promising target for optimization.